# iPhone Dev - Question about autorelease and whether what I'm doing is safe

Tags: iphone, objective-c, autorelease, nsautoreleasepool

I have the following code in a method of my app:

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", nil];

[someObject someMethodThatTakesAnArray:array];
```

I know that the arrayWithObjects method returns an autoreleased array. Does this mean I should retain it directly after it's made? Is it guaranteed that the autorelease pool won't be drained before I pass the array along to someMethodThatTakesAnArray? What about when it gets into the method? If I never retain it, the array could potentially disappear while I'm using it inside the someMethodThatTakesAnArray, couldn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The autorelease pool isn't drained until the next pass of the event loop of the thread it serves. That's not going to happen as long as you're working inside your current method. So yes, array is safe for someMethodThatTakesAnArray: to use; you needn't worry.

Event management: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/Introduction/Introduction.html

Memory management: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html

Comment: ok cool, thanks. do you know of any good resources I could use to learn more about the event loop and how it all works?

Comment: @Tim: Added one more link for your perusal.

Comment: @Tim don't forget to accept the answers that have helped you - it helps other people to know which answers are good, makes people more likely to answer your questions in future and it keeps the community growing

Answer (score 1):

Before your method returns, there's no opportunity for the autorelease pool to get drained.  What you're doing here is fine, if you have no other need for this array than to pass it off to `-someMethodThatTakesAnArray:`